# PowerShell removing like items from files

Tags: powershell

```
$objFolder = "C:\Users\Bruce\Serena\"  #directory
foreach ($file in (Get-Content 'C:\Users\Bruce\process.txt')) {     
Remove-Item -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 'C:\Users\Bruce\sorted.manifest.txt\$file'
}
```

I have this script which removes like items from a directory.  I tried to change
 the directory to a file but it does not remove it.  Do I need to do something different 
 when removing from a file?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are using '' vs "", and hence $file is not being expanded?

Does this produce different result?

```
Remove-Item -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue "C:\Users\Bruce\sorted.manifest.txt\$file"
```

Comment: Tried it same results.  I have test2.txt in process.txt (col 1-9) and in sorted.manifest.txt I have test5.txt 1st line test4.txt 2nd line test3.txt 3rd line test2.txt 4th line and test1.txt 5th line and test2.txt should be removed but it is still there after execution.

Comment: Can you remove -erroraction silentlycontinue, and paste the error?

Comment: I triple checked and the file is there why does powershell not see it  emove-Item : Cannot find path c:\Users\Bruce\sorted.manifest.txt $file' because it does not exist.at c:\Users\Bruce\SQL_PowerShell2.ps1:2 char:3+Remove-Item c:\Users\Bruce\sorted.manifest.txt $file'                                         
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\Bruce\sorted.manifest.txt $file:String) [Remove-Item], ItemNot
   FoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

Comment: Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Bruce\sorted.manifest.txt\ test2.txt' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\Bruce\SQL_PowerShell2.ps1:2 char:3
+   Remove-Item "C:\Users\Bruce\sorted.manifest.txt\ $file"
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\Bruce\....txt\ test2.txt:String) [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundException  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
picking up the test2.txt now but there is a space before the name

Comment: Yes, looks like you have a space in front of your file name. that is coming from get-content part. So your input needs to be trimmed. E.g. "C:\Users\Bruce\sorted.manifest.txt\$($file.trim())"

Comment: Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Bruce\sorted.manifest.txt\$($file.trim())' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\Bruce\SQL_PowerShell2.ps1:1 char:20
+ foreach ($file in (Get-Content 'C:\Users\Bruce\sorted.manifest.txt\$($file.trim( ...
+ CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\Bruce\...$($file.trim()):String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

foreach ($file in (Get-Content 'C:\Users\Bruce\sorted.manifest.txt\$($file.trim())')) {
  Remove-Item "C:\Users\Bruce\sorted.manifest.txt\$file"
}

Comment: Please stop using single quotes.

Comment: Also I did not mean that you need to use that line in Get-Content. You still get your file name like you used to, but then when you issue the command  to remove the file, make sure file name does not have space in front of it, or at the end of it.
 Remove-Item  "C:\Users\Bruce\sorted.manifest.txt\$($file.trim())"

Comment: That worked but still cannot find test2.txt inside of sorted.manifest.txt Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Bruce\sorted.manifest.txt\test2.txt' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\Bruce\SQL_PowerShell2.ps1:2 char:3
+   Remove-Item "C:\Users\Bruce\sorted.manifest.txt\$($file.trim())"
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\Bruce\...t.txt\test2.txt:String) [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

Comment: Well, script cannot be lying to you. Either it really does not exist, or maybe script does not have permissions to it. What do you get when you type in console: get-childitem C:\Users\Bruce\sorted.manifest.txt\test2.txt
Also, why would you name a directory 'sorted.manifest.txt' ?

Comment: sorted.manifest.txt is not a directory is a file and inside the file is literal test2.txt  Bruce is the directory

Comment: I rewrote the script and got the results I wanted except for the output formatting how do I get rid of the headers and => this is my new script                                                     $objManif = "C:\Users\Bruce\sorted.manifest.txt"
$objFile = "C:\Users\Bruce\process.txt"
$FolderReferenceContents = Get-Content $objFile  
$FolderDifferenceContents = Get-Content $objManif
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $FolderReferenceContents -DifferenceObject $FolderDifferenceContents | out-file "C:\Users\Bruce\compare.txt"